# How-to get rid of duplicates in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a database table which stores ids of employees and their previous projects they have been working on. Now I want to retrieve pairs of employees that have been working on the same projects and amount of common projects between these two employees.
If I do "self-join" approach then I get duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id, COUNT(p.id)
FROM employee_project ep1, employee_project ep2, project p
WHERE ep1.project_id=ep2.project_id 
AND ep1.employee_id  ep2.employee_id 
AND p.id=ep1.project_id
GROUP BY ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id, p.id
```

Result:

employee1 | employee2 | 5

employee2 | employee1 | 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `ep1.employee_id >= ep2.employee_id` to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new table with a unique index over the columns that you want to keep unique. Then do an insert from the old table into the new, ignoring the warnings about duplicated rows. Lastly, I would drop (or rename) the old table and replace it with the new table. In MySQL, this would look like

```
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE tmp ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status);
INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp SELECT * FROM mytable;
DROP TABLE mytable;
RENAME TABLE tmp TO mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to "normalize" the combinations and group on that:

```
SELECT greatest(ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id), 
       least(ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id), 
       count(*)
FROM employee_project ep1
  JOIN employee_project ep2 
    ON ep1.project_id=ep2.project_id 
   AND ep1.employee_id=ep2.employee_id 
  JOIN project p ON p.id=ep1.project_id
GROUP BY greatest(ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id), 
         least(ep1.employee_id, ep2.employee_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like all four column values are duplicated so you can do this -

```
select distinct emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status
from YourTable
```

However if marital status can be different and you have some other column based on which to choose (for eg you want latest record based on a column create_date) you can do this

```
select emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status
from YourTable a
where not exists (select 1 
                   from YourTable b
                  where b.emp_name = a.emp_name and
                        b.emp_address = a.emp_address and
                        b.sex = a.sex and
                        b.create_date >= a.create_date)
```

Comment: How is that in any way related to the question?